# Concatenate 2 parameters in a find expression

Tags: linux, find

I want to write a command that will display all `.c` and `.cpp` files from my computer.

I know that I can use find with `-name` but how can I concatenate the parms to find both file extensions.

Right now I have:

```
find -name "*.cpp"
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution

```
find -regex '.*\.\(c\|cpp\)'
```

In that way you can avoid multiple `-o` logic condition (as you requested in [HerrSerker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476951/herrserker) answer

Comment: You might need to set the reextype as it may be configured different on different systems.

Comment: @HerrSerker: yes, but default EMACS is always configured

Answer (score 1):

Use an OR expression with the `-o` symbol:

```
find . -name "*.c" -o -name "*.cpp"
```

Depending on your system, you may need to escape the dot `\.` to avoid it matching any character -> `-name "*\.cpp"`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess

```
find -name "*.cpp" -o -name "*.c"
```

The `-o` meaning LOGICAL OR

Comment: Yup, that is working but there isn't any way to do that logical using a single -name ?

Comment: @redhat01: yes it is possibile. Take a look to my answer